# Migration from 4.02 to 7 artifactory

Tags: artifactory

I'm using a 4.0.2 version of artifactory.
I'd like to know if it's possible a direct migration from 4.0.2 to actual 7 release or some intermediate steps are needed.
Could someone provide documentation about this topic ?
Tks
Tullio

Answer (score 0):

The Quick answer is **No**.

Upgrading Artifactory from 4.x version to 7.x will require incremental upgrades on the way.

In order to find the best solution, based on your current state of the application, please refer to the guides below:

Upgrading from Artifactory 4.x: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF4X/Upgrading+Artifactory#UpgradingArtifactory-Upgradingfromv3.xorv4.xtotheLatestVersion

Upgrading from Artifactory 5.x: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF5X/Upgrading+Artifactory

Upgrading from Artifactory 6.x & 7.x: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Upgrading+Artifactory#UpgradingArtifactory